# Regex for HTML attribute replacement/addition

Tags: html, regex

I'm looking for a single line regex which does the following:

Given a HTML tag with the "name" attribute, I want to replace it with my own attribute. If that tag lacks the name attribute, I want to implant my own attribute. The result should look like this:

```
<IMG name="img1" ...> => <IMG name="myImg1" ...>
<IMG ...> => <IMG name="myImg1" ...>
```

Can this be done with a single line regex?

Comment: Which regex are you using Perl, Java, awk, etc?

Comment: Perl. But Python/awk/egrep would be just as good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to match every complete "attribute=value" pair, but *capture* only the ones whose attribute name isn't "name".  Then plug in your own "name" attribute along with all the captured ones.

```
s/<IMG
  ((?:\s+(?!name\b)\w+="[^"]+")*)
  (?:\s+name="[^"]+")?
  ((?:\s+(?!name\b)\w+="[^"]+")*)
  >
 /<IMG name="myName"$1$2>
 /xg;
```

Comment: This is a better solution than mine, but it does move the name attribute to the start if it exists later in the tag.

Comment: Is that a problem?  AFAIK, the order of the attributes doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a perfect solution, the spacing and position within the tag may not be exactly what you want, but it does accomplish the goals. This is with a perl regex, but there's nothing particular perl-specific about it.

```
s/(&lt;IMG)((\s+[^&gt;]*)name="[^"]*")?(.*)/$1$3 name="myID"$4/g
```

Comment: This almost works. It fails when the "name" tag isn't the first one.

Comment: That is untrue. Did you test it? the (\s+[^>]) covers preceding attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If, like in your example, the name attribute is always the first one inside the IMG tag, then it's very easy. Search for

`<(?!/)(/w+)\s+(name="[^"]+")?`

and replace with

`<\1 name="myImg1"`

but I doubt that this is what you really want.

If the name attribute can occur in other positions, it gets more difficult.

Comment: Well, since I edit general HTML files, I cannot be sure the attribute is the first one. Actually, I'm quite sure it's not.