# Help with Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Let's assume I do preg_replace as follows:

```
preg_replace ("/<my_tag>(.*)<\/my_tag>/U", "<my_new_tag>$1</my_new_tag>", $sourse);
```

That works but I do also want to grab the attribute of the my_tag - how would I do it with this:

```
<my_tag my_attribute_that_know_the_name_of="some_value">tra-la-la</my_tag>
```

Comment: Thou shalt not use regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: Especially not if thou want to match element attributes.

Comment: As a first step, thou shalt use PHP's [inbuilt XML parsing functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Comment: However, SimpleXML will take an eye for an eye. Errors and invalid markup shall not be forgiven.

Comment: If you have impure markup, use [SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), which will forgive invalid HTML, as we forgive our debtors.

Comment: (Not trying to make fun of you, @Defpult. It's just that "parse HTML with regex" questions pop up almost daily on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Lol @Pekka. You could use just one comment to express yourself.

Comment: @Alex I tried that, but it harms the poetic effect. :)

Comment: Oh, you're just being funny today :)

Comment: @Defpult - Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359601/regex-for-html-attribute-replacement-addition

Comment: [IA IA KTULU FHTAGN](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't use regex. You use a real parser, because this stuff cannot be parsed with regular expressions. You'll never know if you've got all the corner cases quite right and then your regex has turned into a giant bloated monster and you'll wish you'd just taken fredley's advice and used a real parser.

For a humourous take, see [this famous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('#<my_tag\b([^>]*)>(.*?)</my_tag>#',
   '<my_new_tag$1>$2</my_new_tag>', $source)
```

The `([^>]*)` captures anything after the tag name and before the closing `>`.  Of course, `>` is legal inside HTML attribute values, so watch out for that (but I've never seen it in the wild).  The `\b` prevents matches of tag names that happen to *start* with `my_tag`, preventing bogus matches like this:

```
<my_tag_xyz>ooga-booga</my_tag_xyz><my_tag>tra-la-la</my_tag>
```

But that will still break on `<my_tag>` elements wrapped in other `<my_tag>` elements, yielding results like this:

```
<my_tag><my_tag>tra-la-la</my_tag>
```

If you know you'll never need to match tags with other tags inside them, you can replace the `(.*?)` with `([^<>]++)`.

I get pretty tired of the glib "don't do that" answers too, but as you can see, there are good reasons behind them--I could come up with this many more without having to consult any references.  When you ask "How do I do this?" with no background or qualification, we have no idea how much of this you already know.

Comment: Good answer: practical, shows why the standard response is "don't do that", points out the pitfalls of the proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Forget regex's, use this instead:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).